# How to redirect to page which has GET parameters after login using the {{next}} variable in django

Tags: django, session, url, redirect

I am using `allauth` to provide registration and login in my django site. Everything else seems to be working fine other than that I am having problems to redirect the person to the current page after login.

I have a page where I have some interview questions and a typical url for it would be like

```
/questions/?company=google
```

This page contains a list of questions for the company google, but to view the answer the person needs to login. The answers are displayed in a dropdown box. However when the user clicks on login a request is sent to the `login` page as follows

```
/login/?next=/questions/
```

And the get parameter which was actually there in my actual page is not sent because of the `&` in my url. How can I solve this problem. It does not look nice that the person is redirected to a different page from where he/she tried to login.

I know sending the `next` parameter as a `GET` variable is not the solution, but is there a way I can send the `redirect link` as a `POST` variable from the template.

I tried another thing, in my view that displays the questions list. I set session variables which contains the url of the current link . If a user clicks on login, in my login view I check for this particular session variable. If it is set then I redirect to that page.

However the session variable is not received in the login view, I am not sure but I think the session is reset when the user goes to the login view.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the URL-parameter in this case. You want to send a variable like `/questions/?company=google`, but as you mentioned the `?`, `=` (amongst others) characters are special ones. It has a special meaning when embedded in the URL. If you [encode](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php) the variable with URL encoding, it becomes `%2Fquestions%2F%3Fcompany%3Dgoogle`. If you assign that to the parameter `next`, the URL becomes: `/login/?next=%2Fquestions%2F%3Fcompany%3Dgoogle`. This should redirect to the correct place on login.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
next = request.get_full_path()
```

This will return correct path with all queries ( see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/?from=olddocs#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) ) , you can then pass it as GET param to redirect url e.g.

```
full_path = request.get_full_path()
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (reverse('login'), full_path))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I wanted to do this in the template and not the view. Within the view it was simpler, but the solution below did the trick