# How to add query parameters to django-allauth LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL?

Tags: javascript, python, django, facebook, django-allauth

1. My JS file is embedded on a third party page
2. the JS file talks to my server using a jsonp request which returns a value which gets stored inside variable `x`
3. now i want to authenticate this user but to do that correctly(for my app logic to work) i need the value of `x` stored inside the JS specific to the third party page
4. I use facebook login through allauth

`window.open("http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/?method=oauth2", "AskAFriend Facebook Login","menubar=0,toolbar=0;scrollbars=0;dialog=0;resizable=1,width=480px,height=320px");`

1. the code above opens a new window for the facebook login process, which when completed redirects to a view i have designed in my django app, i have achieved this by providing the url to this view in the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting in `settings.py`
2. now **i need a way to add a parameter to this request which can reach my view after the login completes, how can i achieve this?**
3. i have tried adding it to the url i used in my JS like  `window.open("http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/?method=oauth2&*valueofx=' + x* ...` (did not work)(ignore the *)
4. I have read about overriding the `get_login_redirect_url()` function by using a custom adapter but i can't figure out how to do it for my specific case

Answer (score 0):

You could change `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to something like `/redirect` and this will in turn be an 'intermediary' view that controls where the user gets redirected to.

That view could look something like this (untested):

```py
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LoginRedirectIntermediary(View):
    """
    Decides where a newly logged in user should go based on the request.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            url = '/admin-panel/{}/'
        else:
            url = '/user-panel/{}/'

        return HttpResponseRedirect(url.format(request.user.username))
```

Comment: but how do i pass my parameter in the first place?

Comment: I tried passing it after the method parameter as shown in the JS code in my question but got an error when i tried to access it in my view.
The JS code is present on a 3rd party website.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood your question. In that case have you looked into the `next` parameter? you might be able to URL encode a full URL and pass it as a value to `next`.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942507/how-to-redirect-to-page-which-has-get-parameters-after-login-using-the-next).

Comment: I have edited my question will that change your answer?